# MySQl Query giving wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Select * from YogaTimeTable;

Delete 
from YogaTimeTable
Where RoomNum IN (select tt.RoomNum
                  from YogaRooms r, 
                       YogaTypes t, 
                       YogaTimeTable tt 
                  where r.RoomNum = tt.roomNum
and ((r.RoomCapacity * t.ClassPrice) - (r.CostPerHour * tt.duration / 60)) < 200);

Select * from YogaTimeTable;
```

The goal is to delete any classes from the timetable that can make less than $200 profit. To calculate the profitability of each class, multiply the roomcapacity by the classprice and then subtract the cost of the room. To calculate the cost of the room multiply the costperhour by the duration divided by 60.
but it isn't giving the right result, can someone tell me where I made my mistake. Thanks. The tables are attached.

[image]

Comment: at first blush you have 3 tables being joined in the subquery but only one join criteria for the tables.  If you use the inner join syntax vs `,` notation this would be more obvious and such oversights wouldn't be missed.  Specifically you said how r and tt relate `r.roomnum = tt.roomnum`  but you've not stated how  but not r and t or tt and t relate

Comment: Select * from YogaTimeTable;

Delete 
from YogaTimeTable
Where RoomNum IN (select tt.RoomNum
                  from YogaRooms r, 
                       YogaTypes t, 
                       YogaTimeTable tt 
                  where r.RoomNum = tt.roomNum and tt.YogaID = t.YogaID
and ((r.RoomCapacity * t.ClassPrice) - (r.CostPerHour * tt.duration / 60)) < 200);

Select * from YogaTimeTable;

Comment: after i joined the other two tables the result is the same, it is deleting the wrong classes...

Comment: on second pass roomNum isn't your key it in YogatimeTable.  It appears the YogaID, starttime, day, and room number make a unique key  so you need to delete based on this full key.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you have two problems.

1. A cross join between t and tt exists and should be resolved.
2. You're attempting to  delete based on an incomplete or partial key of YogaTimeTable.  The Unique Key of YogaTimeTable ***appears*** to be YogaID, StartTime,Day and RoomNum.  I say this because the same yoga type could be in the same room at the same time on a different day, or in the same room on the same day at different start times.  Thus I think the unique key for YogaTimeTable is a composite key of those 4 fields.  So when deleting you need to use the complete key, not a partial key.

So this would result in.
.

```
DELETE FROM YogaTimeTable
WHERE exists 
(SELECT 1
 FROM YogaRooms r
 INNER JOIN YogaTimeTable tt 
   on r.RoomNum = tt.roomNum 
 INNER JOIN YogaTypes t
   on tt.YogaID = t.YogaID 
 WHERE YogaTimeTable.YogaID = TT.YogaID
   and YogaTimeTable.RoomNum = TT.RoomNum
   and YogaTimeTable.StartTime = TT.StartTime
   and YogaTimeTable.Day = TT.Day
   and ((r.RoomCapacity * t.ClassPrice) - (r.CostPerHour * tt.duration / 60)) < 200);
```

According to: I can use a correlated subquery to delete I just can't alias the table.... https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2920

Comment: I see what you mean I didn't know that.. but when I try to run the query it says Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line number 3
Incorrect syntax near 'YTT'.

Comment: @strawberry just a copy/paste from the original.  you're right not needed.

Comment: In regards this Answer and the Answers you have received to other questions, if an Answer to a Question solves the problem that you have specified and it is the best quality Answer of all the Answers to that Question, you should click on the tick next to the top of the Answer.  This provides a small reward to the person who provided the Answer and removes your Question from StackExchange'ss list of unanswered Questions.

Answer (score 1):

Profitability of all classes...

```
select ytt.YogaID,
       ytt.Day,
       ytt.StartTime,
       ytt.RoomNum,
       yt.ClassPrice,
       ifnull(ytt.Duration,0) as Duration,
       ifnull(yr.CostPerHour,0) as CostPerHour,
       ifnull(yr.RoomCapacity,0) as RoomCapacity,
       round(  ifnull(yr.RoomCapacity,0)*yt.ClassPrice
               - (ifnull(yr.CostPerHour,0)*ifnull(ytt.Duration,0)/60)
             , 2) as Profitability
  from YogaTypes yt
  left join YogaTimeTable ytt on (ytt.YogaID=yt.YogaID)
  left join YogaRooms yr      on (yr.RoomNum=ytt.RoomNum);
+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| YogaID | Day       | StartTime | RoomNum | ClassPrice | Duration | CostPerHour | RoomCapacity | Profitability |
+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| DRU    | Wednesday | 10:30:00  |       1 |      18.50 |    60.00 |      100.00 |           20 |        270.00 |
| DRU    | Tuesday   | 17:00:00  |       2 |      18.50 |    90.00 |       50.00 |           10 |        110.00 |
| SUN    | Monday    | 07:30:00  |       3 |      18.00 |    60.00 |      150.00 |           25 |        300.00 |
| HAT    | Tuesday   | 07:30:00  |       4 |      20.00 |    90.00 |       70.00 |           15 |        195.00 |
| HAT    | Monday    | 18:30:00  |       4 |      20.00 |    60.00 |       70.00 |           15 |        230.00 |
| NULL   | NULL      | NULL      |    NULL |      17.00 |     0.00 |        0.00 |            0 |          0.00 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+----------+-------------+--------------+---------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The classes with profitability less than desired...

```
select ytt.YogaID,
       ytt.Day,
       ytt.StartTime,
       ytt.RoomNum
  from YogaTypes yt
  left join YogaTimeTable ytt on (ytt.YogaID=yt.YogaID)
  left join YogaRooms yr on (yr.RoomNum=ytt.RoomNum)
  where ifnull(yr.RoomCapacity,0)*yt.ClassPrice
        - (ifnull(yr.CostPerHour,0)*ifnull(ytt.Duration,0)/60) < 200;
+--------+---------+-----------+---------+
| YogaID | Day     | StartTime | RoomNum |
+--------+---------+-----------+---------+
| DRU    | Tuesday | 17:00:00  |       2 |
| HAT    | Tuesday | 07:30:00  |       4 |
| NULL   | NULL    | NULL      |    NULL |
+--------+---------+-----------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now to delete the undesirable sessions...

```
delete tt.*
  from YogaTimeTable tt,
       (select ytt.YogaID,
               ytt.Day,
               ytt.StartTime,
               ytt.RoomNum
          from YogaTypes yt
          left join YogaTimeTable ytt on (ytt.YogaID=yt.YogaID)
          left join YogaRooms yr on (yr.RoomNum=ytt.RoomNum)
         where ifnull(yr.RoomCapacity,0)*yt.ClassPrice
               - (ifnull(yr.CostPerHour,0)*ifnull(ytt.Duration,0)/60) < 200
       ) as unprof
 where tt.YogaID=unprof.YogaID
   and tt.RoomNum=unprof.RoomNum
   and tt.Day=unprof.Day
   and tt.StartTime=unprof.StartTime;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I would think the final result needs to include day as part of the join.  You could have the same type on the same time of day for the same room on a different day of week.

Comment: Ahhh... I made the assumption the cost wouldn't change.. but I see now hours, etc... can be different.  I updated the answer to include Day.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have a question why when I try to run the query it is returning a null row?

Comment: 'ifnull' is not a recognized built-in function name. I have to remove it why it doesn't recognize ifnull?

Comment: the query is running perfect if I remove the (ifnull) do I need them because I already now the table doesn't have null values and they don't work with them.

Comment: Select ytt.YogaID,
       ytt.Day,
       ytt.StartTime,
       ytt.RoomNum
       ytt.instructor
       ytt.duration
  from YogaTypes yt
  left join YogaTimeTable ytt on (ytt.YogaID=yt.YogaID)
  left join YogaRooms yr on (yr.RoomNum=ytt.RoomNum)
  where yr.RoomCapacity * yt.ClassPrice
        - yr.CostPerHour * ytt.Duration / 60 < 200);

Comment: the select statement above is working and it shows the correct results but when I put it in the delete statement it deletes everything.. why is that?